# foreign mal ingresada

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Llevo horas con este error:

---

Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `prueba`.`montaje` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

---

¿Alguien me podría decir que tengo mal en mi código?

```
CREATE TABLE Montador
(ID_Montador int NOT NULL,
RUT VARCHAR (13) NOT NULL,
primary key (ID_Montador),
Foreign key (RUT) references Persona (RUT));

CREATE TABLE Modelo_Dormitorio
(Cod_Modelo VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
Nombre_Dormitorio VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
primary key (Cod_Modelo));

CREATE TABLE Montaje
(Cod_Modelo int NOT NULL,
ID_Montaje int NOT NULL,
Fecha_Montaje VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ID_Montador int NOT NULL,
primary key (ID_Montaje),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Montador) references Montador (ID_Montador),
FOREIGN KEY (Cod_Modelo) references Modelo_Dormitorio (Cod_Modelo));
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando creas llaves foráneas debes tener en consideración que los campos elegidos para funcionar como `llaves foráneas` deben ser del mismo tipo; entonces tu respuesta debería ser así

```
CREATE TABLE Montador
(ID_Montador int NOT NULL,
RUT VARCHAR (13) NOT NULL,
primary key (ID_Montador),
Foreign key (RUT) references Persona (RUT));

CREATE TABLE Modelo_Dormitorio
(Cod_Modelo VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Nombre_Dormitorio VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
primary key (Cod_Modelo));

CREATE TABLE Montaje
(Cod_Modelo VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
ID_Montaje int NOT NULL,
Fecha_Montaje VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ID_Montador int NOT NULL,
primary key (ID_Montaje),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_Montador) references Montador (ID_Montador),
FOREIGN KEY (Cod_Modelo) references Modelo_Dormitorio (Cod_Modelo));
```

**DETALLES**

> 1. tabla modelo_dormitorio tiene una columna llamada `Cod_Modelo` que es un `VARCHAR(30)`
> 2. en la tabla Montaje tienes una llave foránea llamada `Cod_Modelo` pero en vez de ponerla como `VARCHAR(30)` le pusiste que sea de tipo
>      `INT` entonces por eso te dice que la llave foránea esta formada de
>      manera incorrecta
> 3. A pesar de que `VARCHAR(10)` y `VARCHAR(30)` son equivalentes por ser del mismo tipo, no lo son por ser de distinta longitud, entonces
>      debes colocar mismo tipo de dato y misma longitud, quiero decir en
>      ambas tablas coloca `VARCHAR(30)`

Comment: muchas gracias, recién estoy empezando y no comprendía como solucionar ese error, hubo un momento que pensé que podría ser que las claves foraneas no se ingresaban de esa forma

Answer (score 0):

En esta foreign key:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Cod_Modelo) references Modelo_Dormitorio (Cod_Modelo));
```

el problema es que `Cod_Modelo` en `Modelo_Dormitorio` es un `Varchar(30)` y en `Montaje` es un `int`.

No pueden ser diferentes.